# Kotlin Retrofit POST, error 400

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, post, retrofit

Estoy haciendo un login donde mando el email y password por un POST pero me manda un mensaje 400, la URL es la siguiente:

https://eland-services.humaneland.net:8443/HumaneTime/api/Authorization/AccesoUsuario

Params:

- email: user@hotmail.com
- password: 35869356

Mi interface de retrofit es el siguiente:

```
interface LoginService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("AccesoUsuario/")
    suspend fun loginAccess(@Body params: Params): Response<*>
}

private var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://eland-services.humaneland.net:8443/HumaneTime/api/Authorization/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()

var service: LoginService = retrofit.create<LoginService>(LoginService::class.java)
```

Mi Objeto o body:

```
data class Params(val email:String, val password:String)
```

Mi repository:

```
suspend fun loginAccess(email: String, pass: String){
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            try {
                val loginService = service.loginAccess(Params(email, pass))
                if (loginService.isSuccessful){
                    Log.d("LoginRepository", "Is Successful")
                }else{
                    Log.d("LoginRepository", "Is dont Successful")
                }
            }catch (e: UnknownHostException){
                Log.d("LoginRepository", e.toString())
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Al realizar la petición y obtener un error 400, indica una mala petición (Bad Request) que indica que el servidor no podrá procesar tu solicitud, ya que tal vez la información que le envías no es la adecuada.

Puedes ver que con los datos que proporcionas la solucitud no se puede procesar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**debes verificar y asegurar que valores exactamente necesita la petición**.